# Dictionary containing objects to be used in lock operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

In cases where I have a non-thread-safe object (such as a NetworkStream) that needs to be accessed from multiple threads, is it safe to hold an object to be used for locking, to protect the non-thread-safe object, in the value of a ConcurrentDictionary (or regular Dictionary)?

i.e. that way, I could have multiple threads each attempting to write data to the client's NetworkStream, but only one allowed in at each time?

I'm assuming this is safe since object is reference type, but was hoping someone would be able to confirm.

Example using ConcurrentDictionary.  The Send() method would be called by the multiple threads.  The goal is to allow multiple callers to have write access to the NetworkStream and my curiosity is whether or not the object found in the value of the ConcurrentDictionary can be used reliably in this case for locking.

```
// Assume this is prepopulated
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> locks = ...

public void Send(string identifier, byte[] data)
{
  object clientLock = null;
  if (locks.TryGetValue(identifier, out clientLock))
  {
    lock (clientLock)
    {
      // assume we have the TcpClient here
      NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
      ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically you try to implement your own Semaphore using a Dictionary[string, object] to lock onto. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming) But this might be a border case where mutex and binary semaphore overlap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Semaphores_vs._mutexes

Comment: Similar, but this is one lock object per connected client, so a semaphore is not useful here.

Comment: Shouldn't each thread have its own network stream?

Comment: Yes, each client has its own NetworkStream, but NetworkStream is not thread-safe, which is why I'm wrapping it in a lock (there will be many threads contending to write to each client's NetworkStream).

Comment: I misspoke. Please read again. I meant each **thread**.

Comment: Multiple threads in my case, each wanting an opportunity to write to the NetworkStream.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is you may want to rethink your approach. I am not an expert on streams but the way I have seen this implemented is with a single, sequential command stream and a different (new) network stream opened to execute each command.

Comment: Even if there were a single thread accessing the stream, there would still need to be locking to allow multiple consumers of that thread to write to the stream.  I can't modify the approach.  All I need to know is if it is safe to hold the lock objects in a Dictionary or ConcurrentDictionary.  Thanks!

Comment: @JuanR: As I read it: He has one Stream per client. And multiple threads that may want to write said streams. But he wants to make certain that only one thread can write towards each client at the same time. However the design does seem odd. It might even be the result of a XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You're asking a question about safety but not saying what problem you are concerned about being safe *against*. Can you more clearly describe the problem that you are worried about?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have omitted some important details, like how is the dictionary created? Are keys added and removed dynamically, or are they add-only?  Is that a cache without an expiration policy? If so, are you leaking memory, and how fast? What happens when you access the dictionary but the key is not present? Once you've taken one of the locks, what happens inside the lock? Does anything happen that could take *another* lock?

Comment: It'd be great to see a [mcve] of what you're doing. I can't tell if you're exposing the lock objects in a way that would allow rogue code to just take every lock and then choof off down the pub for a pint.

Comment: One of the issues I see with the above code is that you haven't shown how objects are *added* to the `ConcurrentDictionary`. If there was a bug in the code, I'd guess that is where I'd expect it to be.

Comment: Hi @mjwillis, there is no bug in the code.  The ConcurrentDictionary is abstracted away from the consumers.  Eric, to your question, entries are added on connection establishment and teardown, also abstracted away from the consumers.

Comment: I'm getting the sense that the questions asked are focused on the broader elements of the implementation rather than directly answering the question asked - if I have a series of objects as values in a Dictionary, can I safely use them as lockable objects?  Thanks!

Comment: @joelc What's the point in asking people if some code works if you're just going to refuse to provide the code and just assert that it doesn't have any bugs?  If you're that confident your code doesn't have bugs in it, then *why are you asking us if it will work*?

Comment: "The ConcurrentDictionary is abstracted away from the consumers." That's almost certainly wrong.  There should be exactly one class that has *complete* control over accessing the objects that you're locking on.  That's the only way to have code that has any chance of being understandable enough that you won't have deadlocks, race conditions, or other similar issues.  There should be *one* class creating, using, and getting rid of those objects, so that you can be sure it's always done consistently and correctly.

Comment: @joelc "Eric, to your question, entries are added on connection establishment and teardown" And how, precisely, that's done, is what determines whether or not the code behaves correctly, or if it has race conditions, deadlock potentials, memory leaks, etc..  It also doesn't answer many of Erics questions.

Comment: The issue isn't related to those.  Please see my question above.  Yes, these are pertinent details, but don't need to be addressed.  And, I wasn't asking if my code would work.  I was asking about containing lockable objects inside of a dictionary.

Comment: "The ConcurrentDictionary is abstracted..." being almost certainly wrong.  There is exactly one class that has complete control over the objects being accessed.  It seems like you're either not reading what I'm writing or you're intentionally looking for reasons to pick a fight here Servy.

Comment: `there is no bug in the code.` Haha - if I had a dollar every time someone said that. Hell, if I had a dollar everytime **I** said that.

Comment: `I have a series of objects as values in a Dictionary, can I safely use them as lockable objects` Yes. You can lock on any `object` (which is what you are doing). Whether they came from a `Dictionary` or an array or a pinball machine matters not a whit. Now, there may be a race condition elsewhere if two calls come through for the same identifier at the same time - but I can't help with that since (oddly) you refuse to show the code you use for adding entries to the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you @mjwills, this is what I needed to know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just tested and it works as expected.  Thanks everyone for the lively conversation.  When running the sample code below, Worker2 is delayed.

```
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        locks.TryAdd("foo", new object());
        Task.Run(() => Worker1());
        Task.Run(() => Worker2());
        Console.ReadKey();
    } 

    static void Worker1()
    {
        object lockObj = null;
        locks.TryGetValue("foo", out lockObj);
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }

    static void Worker2()
    {
        object lockObj = null;
        locks.TryGetValue("foo", out lockObj);
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case the Dictionary and the mutex in general might be unessesary. Normally you use a **private** object mutex, to avoid deadlocks. That way no other code can try to aquire on lock on this. But in this case both the mutex object and the stuff it is for are de-facto **public**.

If every thread is capable of running lock/unlock on both the ClientStreams and the mutex object, they do not fullfill their purpose. You could just lock on the "ClientStream" instance whatever that is.

Alternatively, make a class, struct or tupel with the types object and ClientStream. That way you have both the Mutex and hte ClientStream together at least.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, the Dictionary and the collection of TcpClients would be together in the server code itself and private, not in the consuming code.  This logic would not be inside the consuming code.  The server is single-threaded (I can't change that).  The consuming code would have a method such as void SendToClient(string identifier, byte[] data), and this code would reside there.